# linux-tools dependency problem

Tags: apt

After upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04, I get the following dependency problem:

```
Preparing to unpack .../linux-tools-4.15.0-34_4.15.0-34.37_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-tools-4.15.0-34 (4.15.0-34.37) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-tools-4.15.0-34_4.15.0-34.37_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/libcpupower.so.4.15.0-34', which is also in package linux-hwe-tools-4.15.0-34 4.15.0-34.37~16.04.1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-tools-4.15.0-34_4.15.0-34.37_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The package `linux-hwe-tools-4.15.0-34` is a leftover from 16.04 and should be removed (`sudo apt remove linux-hwe-tools-4.15.0-34`).